# Android Track Users Location?

Tags: android

I'm playing around with a bit of a game as a way to learn Android and spend more time getting to know the town I just moved to. The premise behind the game is that you get points for visiting various places in the area around you. What I'd like to do is have the app periodically track your location so that when you launch the game again you can see the different places you've been and how many points you accrued for visiting the various places.

It seems like I could use this [github project](https://github.com/yyl/Tracking-map-on-android) as a starting point, but it seems like that just has a long running task on it that seems like it would really drain your phones battery.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of thing?

Comment: Take a look at the location listener and maybe implement it as a service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html be aware of the high power use though

Comment: Maybe this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219285/tracking-user-location

Comment: I totally didn't even thinking about using an alarm to trigger querying the location - that's a really smart idea. I'll play around with that and the location listener as a service. Curious which one plays out better with regards to battery management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this will be battery intensive you should consider using the new FusedLocationProvider https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html